# Javascript: fastest way to read a HUGE object from disk?

Tags: javascript, json, oop, serialization

In Javascript I have a huge object (400.000 words put into a Trie-structure).

It takes about 1-2 seconds to build this object from a dictionary-file, and even longer on a slow mobile device.
I tried JSON.stringify() on this object, but reading this huge json-file is even slower!

So I'm looking for the ***fastest*** way to (un)serialize this object to/from disk.

Could I maybe somehow put the entire memoryblock to disk and retrieve that, or is that absolutely impossible with Javascript?

Comment: Why do you need an object that huge in the first place? Surely the user doesn't need all 400.000 words at once?

Comment: Can you use backend for data manipulation?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what you are doing now so we could suggest optimizations?

Comment: Sounds like a case where an indexddb may be useful

Comment: I do need this entire object at once, because it's for a scrabble like word-game where it has to check thousands of possible words every move.

Comment: Are you using a server side programming language? This sounds like something that should be done by a server.

Comment: No, I'm not, because the word-checking needs to be instant, and should work offline as well (HTML5 packaged as an app). A database solution would just be too slow, so I need the entire object to exist in memory.

Comment: Try working with IndexedDB instead of plain files... It shoud be more performant...